# Tensor Rank for derivatives and integrals

Tags: tensors

How can I go about determining the rank of a tensor if I am taking a derivative or an integral?

For example, I have a 2nd order Tensor, $A_{ij}$ and I take the derivative with respect to $x_i$ or $x_j$, how does this affect the rank? $(dA_{ij}/dx_i)$

What about if I were to take an integral in the same fashion? ($\int(A_{ijk} dx_i)$)

I keep seeing something about covariant differentiation of tensors but as this is my first time dealing with tensors, I am not sure how to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using Einstein notation here? It makes a big difference if you're doing $\partial_i A_{ij}$ or $\partial_k A_{ij}$ i.e. if you're contracting the tensor with the derivative. (The former is a first-order tensor, the latter third-order.)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. As I said I am new to tensors so I am not 100% if it is Einstein notation or not - I am still learning the difference. I am looking at something like      ∂Aij/∂xi. I understand how to find the order when you add/subtract tensors but I am clueless so far when it comes to taking their derivatives or integrals.

Comment: Its not letting me edit my comment above - Thanks for getting back to me. As I said I am new to tensors so I am not 100% if it is Einstein notation or not - I am still learning the difference. I am looking at something like      ∂Aij/∂xi. I understand how to find the order when you add/subtract tensors but I am clueless so far when it comes to taking their derivatives or integrals. Looking at your comment again I am going to take a stab - would ∂Aij/∂xi be 1st order due to starting with a 2nd order tensor and then taking the derivative of one of the subscripts represented in the statement?

Comment: Again, it depends on precisely what you're computing. If you're implicitly summing over the doubled index (Einstein convention) then it'll be a first-rank tensor. But if you're only differentiating with respect to one particular variable---say, $x_1$---then you won't have a first-rank tensor.

Comment: I am just looking to differentiate with respect to a variable, xi...if I differentiate, why would it not be a 1st order tensor? How does differentiating (or integrating) a tensor by a variable with the same indicies (in this case, i) affect its rank?